# Closed form of summation of Legendre polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, special-functions, legendre-polynomials, spherical-harmonics

I am trying to prove that :
\begin{equation}
\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{l}P_l(s) = \log(\frac{2}{1-s + \sqrt{2-2s}})
\end{equation}
where $P_l$ is the $\textbf{Legendre Polynomial}$, i dont know where to start, can you please help me, Thanks

Comment: What if you start from the generating function?

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Hmm.. But the generating function starts from the index $l=0$, what then?

Comment: You can separate that term out, no? $$\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty P_\ell(x)t^\ell=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}-1$$

Comment: My last hint: divide by $t$ and integrate.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician Writing \begin{equation}
\frac{1}{k} = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-zk}dz 
\end{equation}
and using the Generating Function i got that the summation is equal to:
\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{\infty} [\frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{-2z} - 2se^{-z} + 1}}-1]\ dt
\end{equation}

Comment: $G(x,1)$ with $G(x,z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(x)z^n/n$ computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4400746) (the way it's suggested above)