# Proving $\frac{\pi}{2}=\sum^\infty_{l=0} \frac{(-1)^l}{2l+1}\big(P_{2l}(x)+\text{sgn}(x)P_{2l+1}(x)\big)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions, legendre-polynomials, elliptic-integrals

Can someone help me in proving the following:
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}=\sum^\infty_{l=0} \frac{(-1)^l}{2l+1}(P_{2l}(x)+\text{sgn}(x)\cdot P_{2l+1}(x)),
$$
for any value of $x$, $-1\le x\le 1$? (Here $P_l(x)$ is the [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) of degree $l$, and $\text{sgn}(x)$ is the [sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function).)  It's the craziest result I've seen (that the left hand side is actually independent of $x$), and it's seemingly difficult to prove.  I'm thinking maybe you could prove it using elliptic integrals somehow? Or maybe an easier way?

Putting it into the matlab verifies the result (going to high enough $l$).

Comment: Maybe there is a series expansion of the constant function $\pi/2$ ... At least you might be able to prove the equality in $L^2$

Comment: Some notations are not defined. Please define all of them for clarity.

Comment: I tried looking at some expansions for $\pi/2$ on Wolfram's website, but nothing seemed to immediately be helpful.  Also, notations are now defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume $x\in\mathbb{R}$, $|x|<1$. [Then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Asymptotics) $|P_n(x)|=O(n^{-1/2})$ as $n\to\infty$, hence $$F(x,z):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1},\qquad G(x,z):=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P_n(x)\frac{z^n}{n}$$ converge absolutely and uniformly in $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|\leqslant 1\}$, and clearly
\begin{align*}
F(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}P_{2n}(x)&=\frac1{2i}\big(F(x,i)-F(x,-i)\big),
\\
G(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{2n+1}P_{2n+1}(x)&=\frac1{2i}\big(G(x,i)-G(x,-i)\big).
\end{align*}
Both $F(x,z)$ and $G(x,z)$ can be computed using the generating function $$P(x,t):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty P_n(x)t^n=\frac1{\sqrt{1-2xt+t^2}}$$ (here $t\in\mathbb{C}$, $|t|<1$): for $|z|<1$ we then have
\begin{align*}
F(x,z)&=\int_0^z P(x,t)\,dt&&=\log\frac{z-x+\sqrt{1-2xz+z^2}}{1-x},\\
G(x,z)&=\int_0^z\frac{P(x,t)-1}{t}\,dt&&=\log\frac2{1-xz+\sqrt{1-2xz+z^2}},
\end{align*}
and for $|z|=1$ we may take radial limits, by [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem). This gives, for $\color{blue}{x\geqslant 0}$, $$F(x,\pm i)=\log\frac{\pm i+\sqrt{x}}{1+\sqrt{x}},\qquad G(x,\pm i)=\log\frac2{(1+\sqrt{x})(1\mp i\sqrt{x})},$$ then $F(x)=\operatorname{arccot}\sqrt{x}$ and $G(x)=\arctan\sqrt{x}$, hence $F(x)+G(x)=\pi/2$.

The case $|x|<1$ follows by parity, and the cases $x=\pm 1$ are easy to check separately.